# Angular project directory too large

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-cli

I am a beginner with Angular and I know almost nothing about it. I created a simple CRUD app, however, my project file size turned out to be 400MB+ which doesn't make sense.
I have no idea how to reduce it. I am guessing I downloaded libraries that I don't use?

Comment: 400 MB is fine. For example: just check the size of your node_modules directory. There are quite a lot of dependencies resulting in > 95% of the 400 MB. Though, the production build of your app might be around > 20 MB.

Comment: Do ng build --prod and see the result folder and how much it weights. That would be the actual hosted size

Comment: Unfortunately that is normal with npm. I recommend using pnpm instead, because it has a smaller disk usage and is generally faster.

Answer (score 4):

400 MB is fine, I am writing this since `ng new app` from `Angular CLI` itself creates around `370-400MB` node_modules.

If you are concerned about the performance,

I would suggest you to do `ng build --prod` and check all the generated .js files inside your `dist` folder.

If you find your `main.js` and others to be less, then no need to worry.

I cannot comment on the ideal `main.js` size however I personally ensure it to be around `500-750Kb`.

Besides this, I recommend you to keep an eye on you `package.json` dependencies and remove unwanted deps as too many unwanted deps will potentially increase your `npm install` time.

Answer (score 3):

when you create an angular project, it downloads about 400MB of code for node_modules, but all of that code is technically "outside" your project. It's not part of your project. Your project is under the "src" folder. or if you do a build, it will be under the "dist" folder.